# Технологии для онлайн игр с низким временем отклика.

Tags: веб-программирование, php, gameserver, sql

Интересует с помощью каких технологий достигается максимально низкий отклик для многопользовательских игр в веб-браузере? Какую например базу данных использовать? SQLite хороший вариант? В плане языка интересует больше php(хотя, я понимаю он далеко не самый быстрый для cgi), но с удовольствием послушаю другие варианты. И есть какие-нибудь интересные статьи по этому вопросу?

Comment: БД и язык это пол беды! 85% это шустрый сервер!

Comment: Пол беды, кстати, это 50%=). А скорость обмена данными? Вообще есть возможность эффективно хранить данные в оперативной памяти, вообще не прибегая к базе, учитывая, что сложные структуры не нужны.

Comment: возможно но хранить промежуточное состояние всеравно необходимо, ато представьте играли игроки играли и тут ОП - все лягло, наша песня хороша начинай сначала ^^<br>
Естественно хранить инфу в оперативке можно и нужно, но делать это надо с умом и еще раз повторюсь - это вас никак не избавляет от необходимости как-то хранить состояние сервера...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Тут не так в БД проблема, для максимально быстрого отклика используются сокеты...
Именно для игр - рекомендую java или nodejs ( сам выбрал бы последнее ибо выиграш в скорости разработки несмотря на "риск" использования новой технологии )
Сам недавно сильно заинтересовался подобными вопросами, одно я понял ( понимал правда и раньше :) ) наверняка - не так важна БД, важен сервер ( всмысле серверный код )...

По поводу php - в этом случае действительно ИМХО мягко говоря не лучший вариант...

**UPD**
Небольшой пример клиента и сервера с использованием nodejs + socket.io
Логично что для того чтобы все это работало необходимо установить nodejs + скачать socket.io, в этом всем желающим поможет гугл, я же просто приведу пример...

Сервер

```
/*
 * require это подключение, у меня на linux'e установка socket.io происходит
 * прямо из дистрибутива, если вы просто скачали библиотеку то надо указать
 * к ней полный путь
 */
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8010, '127.0.0.1');
//  тут грубо говоря мы пишем - пускай будет веб сокет сервак
//  на 8010 порте и c IP 127.0.0.1

// Навешиваем обработчик на подключение клиента
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // функция переданная в обработчик инициализирует
    // конкретный экземпляр сокета - socket

    // теперь мы с ним законно можем работать

    // ну и чтобы внести хоть какойто смысл в это все
    // сделаем вывод сообщений отправленых клиентом 
    // в консольку...
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("User disconnected");
    });
});
```

Клиент

Для начала нам необходимо подключить скрипт которы и будет работать над подключением и разруливание проблем кроссбраузерности, т.е. если браузер поддерживает WebSocket - использоваться будут именно они, если же нет то пробует создать xhr, long puling  и т.д. и т.п. Впринцыпе вам не нужно особо вникать что да как, достаточно просто создать подключение...
Делается это так

```
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8010/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Думаю тут все понятно...

Ну и наш "основной" скрипт...

```
var socket;    // ну собственно переменная для сокета
var msg=0;     // счетчик отправленных серверу сообщений
onload = function() {
    socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8010'); // конектимся

    //ну а тут вешаем обработчик на подключение...
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        setInterval("socket.send('Какоето сообщение - ' + msg); msg++;", 1000);
        //ну и с интервалом в секунду кидаем cерверу текст и инкриментим наш счетчик...
    });
};
```

Ну собственно все теперь осталось запустить наш сервер и смотреть результат :)
Как видите все парадоксально просто...
PS: после того как написал первый раз нечто подобное сразу же влюбился в nodejs ^^ 
PPS: тестил в мазиле, опере, хрониуме, хроме - проблем обнаружено не было, если у браузера нет реализации WebSocket используются пляски с бубном в клиентском скрипте server.io, возможно даже в IE сработало бы (хотя если вопрос об игре, не думаю что тут есть смысл хоть как-то пытаться писать клиента под IE)

**UPD2**
[Вики socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki/)
[Офф сайт](http://socket.io/)
Кстати читал о событиях и тому подобном не в вики, но тот сайт где я тогда читал навсегда забыт на 10+ страницах гугла :)
PS:сокеты полноценны и позволяют намного большее чем просто отправлять какой-то текст и выводить в консоль, но это, те кому интересно, и так, вскоре, узнают сами :)

Comment: Простите за невежество, а сокеты, это Unix-сокеты, или нечто в низкоуровневом программировании? Еще вспоминается что вроде комбинация порт и ip-адрес сокетом называется.

Comment: да нет это способ передачи данных, идея в том что клиент открывает соедениние с сервером и оно уже не закрывается ( соответственно нет необходимости в ajax'e ). Кстати по поводу аякса - однозначно не вариант, во первых все время передаем лишнюю инфу, во вторых нет четкой связи клиента с сервером...<br>
Вообще идея сокетов примерно такая - привет сервер, привет клиент, ну все погнали... Потом клиент может отправлять любые данные и сервер соответственно, причем сервер может отправлять данные, например изза действий других игроков, что при использовании ajax'a было бы невозможно...

Comment: Кстати в написании веб сокет сервера нет вообще ничего сложного, я вас уверяю...<br>
Есть набор событий, вам (грубо говоря) просто нужно написать ихобработку... Опять тки это астрактно написано, веб сокет сервера могут быть ооочень сложными, хотя, в тоже время, парадоксально простыми. <br>
Вообщем боятся их ожнозначно не нужно, ничего сложного в них нет

Comment: И реализовать это можно, я так понимаю, на nodejs. А клиентская сторона в виде браузера как это все принимает в виде post запросов?

Comment: не совсем, собственно просто погуглите в сторону <b>socket.io</b>, все очень и очень просто... Сейчас напишу простой пример для клиента и сервера

Comment: @AlexWindHope !  Про веб сокет очень интересно. Если правильно понял, можно написать клиента **под браузером**, который по TCP сокету общается с сервером ? Надеюсь это **не Java апплет** ?

Если можно поподробнее (язык, библиотека, как загружается в браузер и т.п.)

Comment: вот вам пример реализации nodejs + socket.io...<br>
Никаких аплетов естественно нет :)

Comment: Отлично. Надеюсь *socket.on('receive', function () {* или что-то для асинхронного чтения существует.

Т.е. это выглядит, как нормальные сокеты, сервер можно писать на чем угодно.


Ссылочку на доку опубликуйте, *плиз*.

Comment: СПАСИБО !!! Теперь, если это в самом деле работает, совсем другое программирование пойдет !

Comment: Я просто проникаюсь глубоким уважением к js.))