# real-time в веб приложениях

Tags: веб-программирование

Много чего понаписано про "real-time в веб приложениях". Но хочется как то по проще :)
Есть вариант открывать сокет flash(client)->php(server). Далее встала ещё одна проблема, например будет банальный чат, и записывать в сокет нужно будет только если в БД появится новая запись, но как узнавать? Бесконечный цикл? - Не, не катит.
Узнал только-только про триггеры, но как я понял по активации триггера можно что нибудь сделать лишь в пределах БД.
Короче, как быть то?
Может быть серверный JavaScript в силах что-то сделать?

Comment: А СУБД какая? В MSSQL например к тригеру пожно прикрутить сторед процедуру, а из нее например кидать запрос на какой нить веб-сервис.
В MySql точно не знаю, но в последних версиях думаю, что-то подобное должно быть, могу уточнить, если интересует.

Answer (score 1):

Советую обратить внимание на Node.JS, вот [тут отличный развернутый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47673/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/47680) по этой теме.
Но сразу предупрежу, что написать полноценный серверный фреймворк врядли получится.

**UPD**: есть некие [костыли](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php) для MySQL. Но я бы не рекомендовал использовать подобную схему, СУБД должна заниматься работой с данными, и ничего не знать про внешнее ПО.
Поэтому правильнее в данном случае будет использовать сокеты. У Вас будут висеть слушатели (listeners) на клиентах и на сервере, и когда какой-то из клиентов будет выполнять действие (добавлять сообщения в базу), сервер сможет оповестить остальных о данном изменении, и никаких бесконечных циклов.