# Что лучше для реализации чата

Tags: node.js, php

У меня вопрос, что лучше годится для реализации чата **php** или **Node.JS**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io + nodejs, JQuery вовсе не обязательно.

Использую эту связку вы сможете обеспечить истинную интерактивность при этом значительно сэкономить ресурсы сервера. Насколько я помню у тебя выделенный сервак? Если да то тут имхо **без вариантов nodejs**.

На php написать не проще ни разу, например простейший telnet чат в nodejs реализовивается примерно так:

```
var net = require('net');
var clients = [];
net.createServer(function(socket){
    clients.push(socket);
    socket.on('data', function(d) {
        for(var i=0,l=socket.length; i<l; ++i) {
            if(socket[i] !== socket) { socket[i].write(d) }
        }
    });
    socket.on('end', function(socket) {
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
    })
}).listen('8088');
```

Чат с испольованием socket.io пишется не сложнее этого. Причем надо понимать разницу между nodejs и php - nodejs хранит состояние в отличии от php, таким образом чат можно написать **вообще без использования базы данных**, а при использовании nodejs совместно с socket.io вы получаете полноценный socket API. Таким образом в коде не будет тупого долбания сервера по setInterval.

Вообщем - экономится трафик, экономятся ресурсы сервера, гораздо большая гибкость, гораздо большая скорость разработки, гораздо больше возможностей. Думаю плюсы очевидны.

Из недостатков можно отметить лишь слабую поддержку браузеров opera (если не ошибаюсь 10.63+), но это не является большой проблемой т.к. это единственный слабоподдерживаемый браузер, например ИЕ поддерживается, если не ошибюсь - то-ли с 5.5 версии, то-ли с 6.0 версии(что, согласитесь - очень и очень круто).

@Миха Николаев - если планируешь писать что-либо серьезное или интересное - предлагаю свою помощь.

В любом случае, будь это элементарный слабонагруженый чат или полноценное высоконагруженное чат приложение - **nodejs**, однозначно, лучше подходит для этих целей, даже если не использовать socket.io (если так важна поддержка оперы 10.63-)

PS: [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47673/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) немного hello world кода с использованием nodejs и socket.io

Comment: >> Из недостатков можно отметить лишь слабую поддержку браузеров opera (если не ошибаюсь 10.63+), но это не является большой проблемой т.к. это единственный слабоподдерживаемый браузер, например ИЕ поддерживается, если не ошибюсь - то-ли с 5.5 версии, то-ли с 6.0 версии

Это вы про что ? Про Web-Socket API ?

в IE 6.0 ??? о_О

Comment: именно так

Comment: вы наверное шутите, Web-Socket API это детище html5. 

возможно идет речь про какую то эмуляцию WebSocket Api на JS, без использования Flash ?

Comment: Даже если это эмуляция, но в коде вам плевать на это и, на деле, работает практически одинково - это имеет какоето значение?

Comment: Да, меня интересует техническая сторона этого вопроса. Можете выдернуть JS для IE6 и разместить где то на пастебине ? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: [офф сайт](http://socket.io/), ставите nodejs, подымаете hello world socket.io сервер, смотрите исходники.

Answer (score 1):

на чистом пхп или node.js ты не напишешь чат, можно ajax'ом на JavaScript и php на сервере, но лучше  jQuery на клиенте вместо javascript, ну можешь и свой node.js на сервер впихать))

Comment: Ну просто пхп говорят будет сильно тормозить т.к. к примеру взять данные из БД и отправить клиенту и по ка это не сделается типа не перейдет  к другому запросу, а вот если таких запросов несколько тысяч то просто пипец, а нод.джеэс в легкою справится с этим, почему??

Comment: трындёжь походу, если бы несколько запросов посылать было нельзя, то пхпэшный сайт было бы невозможно задосить))вон у контакта чаты же вроде на пхп обрабатываются, если не ошибаюсь)

Comment: У них вроде-бы сначала был Jabber, но потом они написали свой сервер для чата с прослойкой **Node.JS**

Comment: значит ошибаюсь) пишите на node.js)) мне на пхп было бы проще)

Comment: Приведите пример простатоты написания чата  на пхп нежели  на нод.джээс

Comment: это было субъективное мнение) я знаю пхп, потому мне и легче) если вы так не хотите на нём писать, то вопрос темы уже становится риторическим)) 

В пхп можно сделать чат ajax'ом который обращается к пхп файлам, разбитым, например: 1 файл - 1 сервис), в каждом: приём GET(например опять же)) ), изъятие данных из базы, вывод - вот и всё, хотя так будет везде по идее

Comment: @Sleepless - вы хоть пару строчек на nodejs писали? 

"который обращается к пхп файлам, разбитым, например: 1 файл - 1 сервис), **в каждом**: приём GET(например опять же)) ), **изъятие данных из базы**, вывод"

Это по вашему просто? Да и накладно для сервака "малеха", не находите?

Comment: @AlexWindHope нет, не писал, если вы не заметили, то написано: МНЕ легче, если упростить обращение к базе, то не капли не трудно, 
<code>  
connect($login,"$pas");  
$mes  = get("mes");  
insert("messages",$mes);  
$rez = $select("messages","");  
for ($r = array();$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rez), echo $r['text']);  
</code>  
если тут принятие get-данных сделать функцией get, подключение к базе функцией connect, все mysql_query заменить на select, insert, (т.е. не заменить, а написать конкретные функции), то, чат будет работать так, а на клиенте jQuery, тож код небольшой))))

Comment: если написание вышеперечисленных функций не считать, но зато потом будет удобнее))

Comment: Какбы я подразумеваю что БД вообще вынесена в отдельный класс и все инкапсулировано - всеравно php тут не соперник для ноды

Comment: >> но лучше jQuery на клиенте **вместо** javascript

:DD

Comment: @shurik имелось ввиду вместо чистого javascript )

Comment: Вообще реально написать на чистом php сервер сообщений, даже можно использовать сокеты,можно и не использовать сокеты) если реализовать множество функций например сжатие трафика, и многое другое, для сокетов требуется написать нехитрый класс или использовать чужие классы. Все что писали выше типо "Чат с испольованием socket.io пишется не сложнее этого. Причем надо понимать разницу между nodejs и php - nodejs хранит состояние в отличии от php" Это полная ересь, вопрос вы пишите сервер или просто открытие странички? Я подумываю в будующем перейти с php на чистую джаву для написания.