# Постоянное соединение web-приложения

Tags: web-apps

Есть вопрос, но судя по всему не получается правильно сформулировать, поэтому в гугле информации пока найти не могу. Меня интересует можно ли создать постоянно подключение между страницей, которая отдана клиенту и сервером и чем это можно реализовать? Я понимаю, что альтернативный вариант это ajax, который будет обновляться раз в 1 секунду, к примеру, но мне бы хотелось найти решение аналогичное, допустим, прослушиванию портов демонами. Развернутый ответ не нужен - хочу узнать какие маны читать.

Comment: слово на a - нетехнический термин, лучше его избегать.
насколько я понял вопрос, надо смотреть в сторону вебсокетов (которые еще не готовы)

Comment: Ну неужели так сложно нажать на ссылку перед тем как писать "умные" фразы? (-_-)

Comment: Ссылка-то как раз весьма глупая.

Comment: Если вы не асилили того, о чем там идет речь - это не говорит о том, что это "глупая ссылка", скорее это говорит о "уме" читающего.

Я вообще поражен "блеском" ваших мыслей - вы сами написали о веб-сокетах и, тут-же, по сути, хороните свою-же мысль.

PS: если у вас раздвоение личности - тогда, конечно, простите и приймите мои искринние соболезнования.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, уж баттхёрт-то я везде узнаю :-) За Гаррета разболелось или?

Comment: Понеслася. По теме: ответ на вопрос получил спасибо @AlexWindHope. Собери ответ из коммента - помечу лучшим.

Comment: @karmadro4 - у вас по существу что-то есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47673/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)  ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: Какая-то напасть. Вы умеете читать мои мысли? :) На 3 из 5 моих вопросов Вы ответили лучше всех xD

Comment: Не исключено ;)

Comment: `eval` сразу характеризует образцовое качество :-)